# mutt doesn't run as a cron job wrapped in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, cron, mutt

mutt runs correctly like this:

```
$ cat /home/user/test
this is a test

$ mutt -s "test" to@destination.org </home/user/test
```

If I put this inside a bash script (stored in `tmp1`):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mutt -s "test" to@destination.org </home/user/test
```

and in cron:

```
00 22 * * * user /bin/bash /home/user/tmp1
```

I see the script getting executed, but mutt doesn't send any email :-/

Also adding to mutt -F option:

```
mutt -F /home/user/.muttrc
```

Comment: If your system is set up to be able to send e-mail, then you could set `MAILTO` in your crontab to receive error messages from your cron job, which would be very helpful in finding out what happened. Also, the syntax you posted is correct for a system-wide crontab; if it is your own user's crontab, then the `user` column is extraneous.

Comment: I just checked: no error message from cron. Thanks!

Comment: This is a rather large guess, so I'll make it a comment; I see from the [mutt manual](https://dev.mutt.org/doc/manual.txt) in section 14 that mutt tries to open a mail folder from $MAIL or $MAILDIR, which may be set in an interactive session but not in a cron session. Add "echo MAIL: $MAIL, MAILDIR: $MAILDIR" into your shell script and then see what cron responds with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `mutt`.

For me, it turned out that `mutt` was trying to send the email from username@gmail.com, where username was my ***machine*** username.

I had set my gmail account as the default within my `.muttrc file`. I checked file `/var/log/syslog` to discover this.

I solved my problem by using `msmtp` instead of `mutt`. The arch linux wiki gives examples of suitable installation parameters. Downside is that it does not allow attachments, although there may be some way to fix that.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/msmtp

The command line below works for me within cron:

```
cat test.file | msmtp --from=default -t username@domain.com
```

This will send an email, but the `To` box and the `Subject` box will not render well, if at all. If this doesn't matter, then great. When it does, I add them to the beginning of `test.file`, as below:

```
To: recipient@recipient.com

Subject: subject line

test.file contents
```